# Either the class "FourthWindow" doesn't show stacklayout or its the only thing on the screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class ScrollViewExample(ScrollView):
    pass


class FirstWindow(Screen):
    def set_text(self):
        my_title_input = self.ids.note_title
        my_details = self.ids.note_details
        fo = open("notes.txt", "a")
        fo.write('\n'+'\n'+my_title_input.text)
        fo.write('\n'+my_details.text)
        fo.close()


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    def on_toggle_button_state(self):
        dark_mode = self.ids.dark_mode
        dark_mode.text = 'Feature not available'
    pass


class FourthWindow(Screen):
    #This class displays notes from a file in buttons
    #works but only the notes showup
    def build(self):
        root = FourthWindow()
        root.add_widget(FourthWindow(name='StackLayout'))

        class StackLayoutExample(StackLayout):

            class ScrollView(ScrollView):
                pass

            def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                super().__init__(**kwargs)
                layout = StackLayout(orientation='lr-tb')
                with open('notes.txt', 'r') as fp:
                    data = fp.read()
                    splat = data.split("\n\n")
                    notes = []
                    for i, note in enumerate(splat, 0):
                        notes.append(note)
                    for i in range(0, len(notes)):
                        b = Button(text=notes[i], size_hint=(.25, .4))
                        self.add_widget(b)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class RelativeLayoutExample(RelativeLayout):
    pass


class ScreeManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class LineMaker(Widget):
    pass


class Noteit(App):
    pass


Noteit().run()
```

```
Noteit.kv       <---The kv file begins here
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:
    ThirdWindow:
    FourthWindow:


<FirstWindow>:
    id: first_window
    name: "Notes"

    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Notes"
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'center_x':.5}
            font_size: 35
        Button:
            text: 'Account'
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'right':1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Account"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left"
        Button:
            text: 'Preferences'
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'left':1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Preferences"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "right"
        Label:
            text: "Title:"
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':.85,'center_x':.5}
            font_size: 20
        TextInput:
            id: note_title
            size_hint: .45,.08
            pos_hint: {'top':.75,'center_x':.5}
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: "Details:"
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':.65,'center_x':.5}
            font_size: 20
        TextInput:
            id: note_details
            size_hint: .45,.3
            pos_hint: {'top':.55,'center_x':.5}
            multiline: True

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            size_hint: .25,.1
            length: "100dp"
            pos_hint: {'top':.25,'center_x':.5}
            on_release:
                root.set_text()
        LineMaker:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Line:
                    width: 2.
                    points: (self.width,self.height*.83,0,self.height*.83)
        Button:
            text: 'View All Notes'
            size_hint:.25,.15
            pos_hint: {'bottom':1,'center_x':.5}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "View"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "up"


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "Account"


    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Account"
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'center_x':.5}
            font_size: 35
        Button:
            text: 'Notes'
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'left':1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Notes"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "right"
        Button:
            text: 'Preferences'
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'right':1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Preferences"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left"
        Label:
            text: "Username:"
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':.85}
            font_size: 20
        TextInput:
            size_hint: .5,.1
            pos_hint: {'top':.55,'left':.3}
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: "Password:"
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':.65}
            font_size: 20
        TextInput:
            size_hint: .5,.1
            pos_hint: {'top':.75,'left':.3}
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "Log In"
            size_hint: .25,.1
            length: "100dp"
            pos_hint: {'top':.45}
        Button:
            text: "Sign Up"
            size_hint: .25,.1
            length: "100dp"
            pos_hint: {'top':.45,'center_x':.375}
        LineMaker:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Line:
                    width: 2.
                    points: (self.width,self.height*.83,0,self.height*.83)




<ThirdWindow>:
    name: "Preferences"

    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Preferences"
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'center_x':.5}
            font_size: 35
        Button:
            text: 'Notes'
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'right':1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Notes"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left"
        Button:
            text: 'Account'
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'left':1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Account"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "right"
        ToggleButton:
            text: 'Dark Mode'
            size_hint: .25,.1
            pos_hint: {'top':.75,'center_x':.25}
            on_state: root.on_toggle_button_state()
        Label:
            id: dark_mode
            text: ''
        LineMaker:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Line:
                    width: 2.
                    points: (self.width,self.height*.83,0,self.height*.83)

<FourthWindow>:
    name: "View"
    RelativeLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Note Submission'
            size_hint:.25,.15
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'center_x':.5}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Notes"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "down"
        Label:
            text: 'All Notes'
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'right':.9}
            font_size: 35
```

How do I make the stacklayout code showup with the kv file code? Or at least make the stacklayout part of the screen.
Right now the only option I have is either take the screen as output or the stack layout as output.
Replacing the `def build(self)` inside the `class FourthWindow(Screen)` will show the whole application. The code inside the `def build(self)` also works but they do not work together.
I am new to kivy and object oriented programming so I do not know much about this topic so I could be missing something really basic.

Comment: `Screen` widgets have no default method named `build`. Instead of creating nested classes try defining them separately and add those in `__init__`.

Comment: @ApuCoder could you write a the code for the '__init__' part? I don't think I understand.